# Resources in APIRestful

Tags: rest, api, restful-architecture

I have read several things about API's but there is something that is not clear to me on the subject of how to structure the `resources`. I will give you an easy but illustrative example. We imagine we have this relationship:

```
|Clients| (1:1) ------<>----- (0:M) |Orders| (1:1) ------<>------ (1:1) |Statuses|
```

A client can have zero or many orders and each order has a status.

The question comes when making resources, the resources that are clear are as follows:

```
GET /clients (get a list)
GET /clients/10 (get detail of one client)
POST /clients (create a client passing data by BODY)
```

(there could be more like the `PUT` but to simplify the example I simplify.)

The question is, to get the **Orders** from a **Customer** such as the `resource`?

```
GET /clientes/10/orders
```

Or in place:

```
GET /orders?id_cliente=10
```

The same to get the detail of an **Order**, what would it be like?

```
GET /clientes/10/orders/10
```

Or it would simply make sense to do this (which would also show the information of the **State** that you have):

```
GET /orders/10
```

Or when you want to delete an order:

```
DELETE /orders/10
```

or

```
DELETE /clientes/10/orders/10
```

And to create an **Order**, should the **Customer** always exist or could a **Order** and a **Customer** be created at the same time with the following resource? For example, a **Customer** not registered when making a purchase will place the **Order** and register at the same time)

```
POST /orders
```

Passing the **Customer** data in the `BODY` to it as the **Order** data would go. First the **Customer** would be created and then the **Order**.

If there is anyone who knows what all the valid resources of the sample relationship would look like, it would be good to share them. I don't want to get into paginate topics or other topics that are also important in an API. Only in the matter of resources.

Comment: [This is no `REST`.](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven)

Comment: [Book recommended by Fielding.](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028468.do)

Answer (score 1):

To resolve you confusion, you can just ask yourself the following questions.

1. Does my resource have a unique resource id? - There should not be multiple resource elements pointing to a same resource.
2. Whether child resource can exist without the parent? - If it can exist, then it should not be considered as a child resource, but has to be concluded as individual resources.

In your case, according to the above, it is clear that the **clients** resource is a parent of **orders** resource. So the API endpoints must be,

```
/clients (GET) - get all clients
/clients/$client_id (GET) - get a client
/clients/$client_id/orders (GET) - get all orders of the particular client
/clients/$client_id/orders (POST) - create new order for the client
/clients/$client_id/orders/$order_id (PUT) - Modify the particular order for the client
/clients/$client_id/orders/$order_id (DELETE) - Delete the particular order for the client
```

And for your last question on creating a parent resource when a child resource create api called,
Refer [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50192133/is-it-restful-to-create-a-foreign-key-record-from-another-resources-post-request/50200098#50200098)

Note : Sorting, filtering, limits and pagination can be supported using query parameters in your APIs.

Comment: But, could you have a resource /orders that gets all the Orders (whoever they are)? Or would that be a bad way to do it?

Comment: If such APIs are allowed based on whoever they are, will it be of any help in the clients using your API? Also, you should think twice about the access of others' resources by anyone.